# Prove or give a counterexample to the following claim

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following claim to either prove or provide a counter example, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it if it indeed can be proved, or what to consider in case of counterexample.

> Claim: Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, and suppose that $W_{1}$, $W_{2}$, and $W_{3}$ are subspaces of V such that $W_{1}+W_{3}=W_{2}+W_{3}$. Then $W_{1} = W_{2}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider $W_1=\langle (1,0) \rangle$, $W_2=\langle (1,1) \rangle$, $W_3=\langle (0,1) \rangle $.

Comment: Consider $W_3=W_1+W_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. For counter example we consider any two distinct subspace $W_1,W_3$ of dimension 1. Since we can just pick an element $v\in W_{1}+W_{3}$ such that $v\notin W_1,W_3$ and let $W_2=span(v)$, we obtain $W_{1}+W_{3}=W_{2}+W_{3}$ while $W_1\ne W_2$. (For a concrete example see the comment by Mr.Reveillark)

Note that there can be cases where the relation is not true even if we change the vector space sum to direct sum or add more specification to $V$, such as $V$ being a Hilbert space.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that Reveillark's comment helped me understand the counterexample he proposed, as span has not been introduced in my lecture notes, nor been mention in discussion yet.

Comment: Think about it this way, every point $P$ in the XY-plane can be represented by $P=(a,b)$. In this case we can also say that $P=ae_1+be_2$, where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. When we say a certain subset is spanned by some collection of vectors, it is somewhat "generated" by those vectors (you can look up a formal definition of that in Wikipedia), observe that $span(e_1)$ is the X-axis and $span(e_2)$ is the Y-axis.

Comment: Now, suppose I let $v=(1,1)$, then $v$ generates a line $x=y$. Ask yourself this question: Can we write EVERY points in the plane in the form $P=ce_1+de_3$? In turn out that the answer is YES (and the numbers $c,d$ are also unique for this purpose). This is what we mean when we say that XY-plane is of $dimension 2$, every points can be represented by the _scaled_ combination of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: As you can see, the Y-axis and the line $x=y$ are not the same but together with the X-axis, both pair generate the XY-plane. This is the counter example to the claim.